# How to access "value" property in viewCategoryColumn

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am using a DataView control from the extension library in my mobile application.
The category column contains the value from a categorized view too display the status of a document. ( values are 0 and 1 )
I would like to translate the values in the DataView Control depending on the language, the user has selected. So I need to build the key from this value to return the value from my language resource file.

the value property of the control contains the current vale.
But how would I access this value?

I would likje to do something like this

```
if (this.Value.equals("0")) {
   return lbls["status.not.activated"];
} else {
   return lbls["status.activated"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any code I can only guess that you might have bound the DataView control to an ordinary DominoView datasource. And furtehr I assume that with "value" you are referring to the value property of the DataView's "viewCategoryColumn" child control.

One thing I see from your code snippet is that you spell the "Value" property with a capital "V", which might be a typo here, but if it's like that in your actual code then this must be wrong.

Apart from that I just tried this in a very simple test scenario where my datasource is a view  using the Form fields as category column. Using a code like the following in my opinion should be the solution for your task as well:

```
<xe:this.categoryColumn>
    <xe:viewCategoryColumn
        columnName="Form"
        columnTitle="Form">
    <xe:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
if(@LowerCase(viewEntry.getColumnValues()[0])=="testform"){
    return "Standard Form";
}else{
    return "Other Form";
}}]]></xe:this.value>
    </xe:viewCategoryColumn>
</xe:this.categoryColumn>
```

The `viewEntry` variable has been defined as a core property for the dataView itself as we do it with many viewPanel, repeats etc, resulting in an object of type `NotesXspViewEntry`:

```
<xe:dataView
    id="dataView1"
    columnTitles="true"
    var="viewEntry">
    ...
</xe:dataView>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thx, I'm sure, I have tired it this way before. Anyhow, your solution works



  <xe:this.categoryColumn>
     <xe:viewCategoryColumn contentType="text">
      <xe:this.columnName>
       <![CDATA[#{javascript:"dd.activated"}]]>
      </xe:this.columnName>
      <xe:this.value>
       <![CDATA[#{javascript:return applLang["view.column.state.active." + viewEntry.getColumnValues()[1]]}]]></xe:this.value>
     </xe:viewCategoryColumn>
    </xe:this.categoryColumn>